# Use of REPL in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, read-eval-print-loop

1. What is the use of REPL in nodejs?
2. What are the use-cases/scenario for using REPL?
3. When should I use the REPL node module in nodejs?

I have understood the API Doc, how to include REPL module and how to start the REPL instance using the prompt and eval.

But can anyone help me to understood above question? So that I can understand how exactly the REPL module can be used?

Comment: ... if you don't need it, you don't need to use it.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it

Comment: The simplest example(not an actual implementation of Node.JS REPL) will be the chrome console. Use REPL if you want to make something like that.

Comment: i have used it to quickly make an crud application to interact with database which had business logic build in it and you could have custom commands to perform actions it was more verbose and fast than trying to build an UI and/or run an web server.

Comment: I test my modules with a REPL instance (`node`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the use-cases/scenario for using REPL?

I've often seen it (or Chrome's console which is a JavaScript [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) as well) used in tech talks as a quick way to demonstrate what different expressions evaluate to. Let's image you're holding a talk about *Equality in JavaScript* and want to show that [`NaN` strangely is not equal to itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN).

You could demonstrate that by:

- running `node` without arguments in your terminal (this starts the REPL)
- entering `NaN == NaN` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the REPL will evaluate the expression)
- pretending to be surprised that the output is `false`

> When should I use the REPL node module in nodejs?

When you want to implement a Node.js REPL as part of your application, for example by exposing it through a "remote terminal" in a web browser (not recommending that because of security reasons).

### Examples

#### Replicating the REPL that is shown by calling `node`

```
const repl = require('repl')
const server = repl.start()
```

#### Using the `REPLServer`'s stream API

*`fs-repl.js` file:*

```
const repl = require('repl')
const fs = require('fs')
const { Readable } = require('stream')

const input = new fs.createReadStream('./input.js')

const server = repl.start({
  input,
  output: process.stdout
})
```

*`input.js` file:*

```
40 + 2
NaN
["hello", "world"].join(" ")
```

You can now run `node fs-repl` and you will get the following output:

```
> 40 + 2
42
> NaN
NaN
> ["hello", "world"].join(" ")
'hello world'
```

This output can obviously be passed into a [`Writable` stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) other than [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) by changing the [`output`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options) option.